# All data deleted From S3 after writing with "overwrite" mode via Databricks

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, hive, databricks

My Agenda -

1. Query Hive External Table and store data in a dataframe.
2. Do some processing on the data frame.
3. Store the processed data into some other S3 Location( i.e partitioning by businessname too in dataframe write).

**Important** - All the above are executed on Databricks Notebook.

So ,
My hive table reads partitions from such location on S3 -

Hive location - `s3://dev/gp/data/tmp/g.p/HistoryData/myDataclass`

Containing Partitions Like-

```
s3://dev/gp/data/tmp/g.p/HistoryData/myDataclass/ingestiontime=20200804230000
s3://dev/gp/data/tmp/g.p/HistoryData/myDataclass/ingestiontime=20200803230000
s3://dev/gp/data/tmp/g.p/HistoryData/myDataclass/ingestiontime=20200802230000
s3://dev/gp/data/tmp/g.p/HistoryData/myDataclass/ingestiontime=20200801230000
```

The Writing To S3 Happens with -

```
data.coalesce(coalesceSize/maxFilterLength)
        .write
        .partitionBy("businessname", "ingestiontime")
        .mode(SaveMode.Overwrite)
        .format(flatDataFormat)
        .option("path", s"${flatteningBasePath}/")
        .save()
```

And the destination location are -

```
s3://dev/gp/data/tmp/g.p/HistoryData/myDataclass/businessname=abc/ingestiontime=20200804230000
s3://dev/gp/data/tmp/g.p/HistoryData/myDataclass/businessname=abc/ingestiontime=20200803230000
s3://dev/gp/data/tmp/g.p/HistoryData/myDataclass/businessname=abc/ingestiontime=20200802230000
s3://dev/gp/data/tmp/g.p/HistoryData/myDataclass/businessname=abc/ingestiontime=20200801230000
.....
s3://dev/gp/data/tmp/g.p/HistoryData/myDataclass/businessname=hell/ingestiontime=20200804230000
s3://dev/gp/data/tmp/g.p/HistoryData/myDataclass/businessname=hell/ingestiontime=20200803230000
s3://dev/gp/data/tmp/g.p/HistoryData/myDataclass/businessname=hell/ingestiontime=20200802230000
s3://dev/gp/data/tmp/g.p/HistoryData/myDataclass/businessname=hell/ingestiontime=20200801230000
....
```

Now, The issue is all of these happen successfully,
But the original data in the hive partitions i.e -

```
    s3://dev/gp/data/tmp/g.p/HistoryData/myDataclass/ingestiontime=20200804230000
    s3://dev/gp/data/tmp/g.p/HistoryData/myDataclass/ingestiontime=20200803230000
    s3://dev/gp/data/tmp/g.p/HistoryData/myDataclass/ingestiontime=20200802230000
    s3://dev/gp/data/tmp/g.p/HistoryData/myDataclass/ingestiontime=20200801230000
```

suddenly have **NO DATA** in them, which is also confirmed when i query the hive table and it returns me `null`.

Upon looking closely, in my s3 folder ( suppose for this partition - `s3://dev/gp/data/tmp/g.p/HistoryData/myDataclass/ingestiontime=20200801230000` ) -

[image]

I am really confused so as to why is this happening, I dont want to loose any data from anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

This was caused because of Spark Dynamic Partitioning.
I was able to control this using the following property set correctly -

```
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.sources.partitionOverwriteMode","dynamic")
```